# How to change the value of timeout for one key command?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, vimscript

### What I want

To temporarily change the timeout value for certain key commands

### Where I've looked

From `:help 'timeout'` I have :

```
The timeout only happens when the 'timeout' and 'ttimeout' options
tell so.  A useful setting would be >
    :set timeout timeoutlen=3000 ttimeoutlen=100
(time out on mapping after three seconds, time out on key codes after
a tenth of a second).
```

I'm not sure how I would implement this in a key command though, or how to check the current setting of timeout.

For example, I wanted to try and set `hh` to go to the start of a line, but I wanted the timeout for that particular key command to be pretty quick, say 100 milliseconds.

### What I've tried

```
:set timeout timeoutlen=100 ttimeoutlen=100
nmap hh <S-^>
:set timeoutlen=1000 ttimeoutlen=1000
```

Comment: Settings like `'timeoutlen'` are used at the time that the mapping is *invoked*, not created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'timeoutlen'` option is a global one, and it applies at mapping *invocation*, not during *definition*.

I can understand your motivation (using a special `hh` mapping while still being able to quickly move via `h`, `h`), but I would nonetheless advise against such tricks. Better choose another mapping that doesn't overlap with a built-in command.

If you really must, have a look at the [arpeggio plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2425). It performs some tricks to map simultaneously pressed keys.

Comment: thanks Ingo, I'm getting a little more creative with mappings recently but still in need of do's and don'ts guidance :)